# Url rewriting for my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have try following code to rewrite the url on my website but its not working properly

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule about/page_id/(.*)/ productlist.php?page_id=$1
```

Not working properly

but following code working fine..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^floratonic\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://floratonic.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I need suggestion for rewriting for this url

```
http://floratonic.com/productlist.php?page_id=44
```

to

```
http://floratonic.com/productlist.php/44/
```

OR

```
http://floratonic.com/productlist.php/PAGENAME/
```

Comment: You do not have a rewrite rule which even seems to affect paths like `productlist.php/44/`.

Comment: *`"but its not working properly"`* is a bad description. What error are you getting?

Comment: no error same page open

Comment: Timesplinter please suggest me the rewrite rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simply:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about/page_id/(.*)/ productlist.php?page_id=$1 [NC, L]
```

Comment: I have try this its working but css of project not call http://floratonic.com/productlist/44 please check it i think its assume productlist as a folder...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/page_id/(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule  ^about/page_id/(.*)/ productlist.php?page_id=$1
```